# Jquery or Javascript or Ajax: Close iframe by clicking on it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I would like to close the `iframe` and `div`, whenever someone clicks any link in `iframe`.

I know it's possible, I've seen some websites doing this.
Just do not remember the url of such websites.

I copied this code on a site a while ago and was used to locate the click inside the `iframe`.

Do not know how to use the script.

```
$.enableFrameClick = function(){
var decoy = $('<a href="#"/>').css({
    position: 'absolute',
    right:0,
    top:0,
    width:1,
    opacity:0
}).click(function(e){ return false }).appendTo(document.body);

$(window).blur(function(){
    if ($.inFrame){
        $('#'+$.inFrame).trigger('click');
        setTimeout(function(){
            decoy.focus();
        }, 10);
    }
});

var ids = +(new Date);
$('iframe').each(function(){
    if (!this.id){
        this.id = ++ids;
    }
    $(this).hover(function(){
        $.inFrame = this.id;
    }, function(){
        $.inFrame = null;
    })
});
};

$('#mha iframe').bind('click', function(){
    $.ifrm(1);
    //log(['[',++i,']','clicked', this.id].join(' '));
});

function log(m){
    //$('#log').text(m);
    //console.log(m);
}

var i = 0;

$.ifrm = function(r){
    $.get("http://www.example.com/"+r, function(html,status){
        $('#mha iframe').attr("src",html);
        if(r == 1)
            html = '';
        if(html == '')
            $('#fanback').remove();
    });
};

$.enableFrameClick();
$.ifrm(0);
```

Comment: Close an iframe? You mean hide/remove from `DOM`?

Comment: Sorry! The div in which is located the iframe. LShetty

Comment: You are not allowed to access the iframe's content unless it's on your server. (or the appropriate access-control-* headers are set)

Answer (score 0):

You may try to use below if what you want is just make the div 'disappear':

```
 $("#button_id").click(function(){
     $("#div_id").hide();
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

You Cant trigger an event (like mouse click) inside a iFrame, but exist some method for do that anyway, like this:

http://jsbin.com/aYijiLe/2

i hope can help you
(i think work also crossdomain, but im not sure about that)

Comment: I updated the question with a script.
Could you tell me how it works? @Aethiss

Answer (score 0):

The iframe node has a contentWindow property, which is the "window" object of the iframe.

```
    var iframe = document.getElementById('the_iframe');
    iframe.contentWindow.document.body.addEventListener('click', function(event {
            //check if target is an anchor tag
            if (e.target.tagName === 'A') {
                    //remove iframe
                    iframe.parent.removeChild(iframe);
            }
    });
```

Note that you can only attach events to nodes inside the iframe, **only** if the iframe source is on the same domain, port, and protocol.

See http://jsfiddle.net/6crygjm3/1/ for a working demo.